# Find string position and join another table's row

Tags: mysql, string, position, inner-join

I have two main questions on getting 2 set of tables.

```
table : room_type
rt_id   rt_title
1       Type A
2       Type B
3       Type C
4       Type D
5       Type E
```

Here is another table to come with.

table: rate_cost

```
id     rate hotel cost                      date
2999    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-01
3000    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-02
3001    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-03
3002    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-04
3003    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-05
3004    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-06
3005    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-07
3006    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-08
3007    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-09
3008    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-10
3009    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-11
3010    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-12
3011    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-13
3012    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-14
3013    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-15
3014    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-16
3015    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-17
3016    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-18
3017    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-19
3018    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-20
3019    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-21
3020    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-22
3021    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-23
3022    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-24
3023    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-25
3024    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-26
3025    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-27
3026    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-28
3027    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-29
3028    7   1   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-30
3028    8   2   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-01
3028    9   3   4700-5400-6100-6600-7300    2012-11-01
```

Each dash separated number is a rate cost regarding to each room type by its position. For example 4700 is a rate cost for Type A (rt_id=1), 5400 is Type B... 7300 is Type E(rt_id=5).

Now I'd like to create a result like following.

```
Day/Room type   Type A | Type B | Type C | Type D | Type E
1 Nov 2012      4700     5400     6100     6600     7300
2 Nov 2012      4700     5400     6100     6600     7300
3 Nov 2012      4700     5400     6100     6600     7300
4 Nov 2012      4700     5400     6100     6600     7300
...
30 Nov 2012     4700     5400     6100     6600     7300
```

I was made those result work in PHP but it cost seconds to complete. I've tried to do on my own but I lack of mySQL knowledge. So please enlighten me.

Comment: YOu should really change your DB structure. Normalize your data to avoid such huge problems you are having right now.

Comment: @juergend. Now I just realized that my DB structure is to hard to work with. But now I really need to pass this problem for some reason. Especially for limitation of time :(

Comment: This reason is a developer's all time companion. Don't think you ever gonna have the time to change it. You should really change it anyway. It will save you a huge load of time in the future.

Comment: @juergend. Thanks for re-statement but now I need to solve it. I have to change it anyway but not right away isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split a string into columns:

```
select date,
       substring_index(cost, '-', 1) type_a,
       case when cost regexp '.*-' then
                 substring_index(substring_index(cost, '-', 2), '-', -1)
            else ''
       end type_b,
       case when cost regexp '.*-.*-' then
            substring_index(substring_index(cost, '-', 3), '-', -1)
            else ''
       end type_c,
       case when cost regexp '.*-.*-.*-' then
            substring_index(substring_index(cost, '-', 4), '-', -1)
            else ''
       end type_d,
       case when cost regexp '.*-.*-.*-.*-' then
            substring_index(substring_index(cost, '-', 5), '-', -1)
            else ''
       end type_e
from rate_cost;
```

If you can modify the table design, it's better to create multiple columns:

```
create table rate_cost (
    id int,
    rate int,
    hotel int,
    cost_type_a int,
    cost_type_b int,
    cost_type_c int,
    cost_type_d int,
    cost_type_e int,
    date date);
```

Comment: What if I have less column than 5? Yeah I strongly agree that I should normalized my DB structure. But not now please.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have always less than 5 columns or does the number of columns vary from row to row?

Comment: sometimes some hotel. For example code 4 or 5 might have 2 or 3 rates: 
`Hotel 4 = 2500-2700
Hotel 5 = 300-3200-3500`

Comment: The last column will be repeated: Hotel 4 = 2500, 2700, 2700, 2700, 2700; Hotel 5 = 300, 3200, 3500, 3500, 3500. If you want empty columns, you must test how many dashes you have. This will become pretty ugly.

Comment: Try the modified answer, it should deliver empty columns, when there are less than 5 rates.

Comment: Olaf, it works like a charm. Thank you very much. You've saved my life.

Comment: Olaf, I have another issue. Wondering if you're also expert in json. I need the info to be fomated into this format:

`{
  "data": [
    ["", "type_a", "type_b", "type_c", "type_d", "type_e"],
    ["2012-11-01", 4700, 5400, 6100, 6600, 7300],
    ["2012-11-02", 4700, 5400, 6100, 6600, 7300],
...
    ["2012-11-30", 4700, 5400, 6100, 6600, 7300]
  ]
}`

Comment: I know about json, but need to look at some manual first. It depends on what language you want to use, so one can choose an appropriate library. I guess there are a lot of json experts here. So, I suggest just post a question or search for questions tagged [tag:json] + your preferred language.