# Re-arrange mysql result in an expected format for hansontable

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm going to re-arrange mysql result into json with a format to use with hansontable.
According to this issue : [Find string position and join another table's row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218232/find-string-position-and-join-another-tables-row/13218284#comment18001930_13218284). Mr.Olaf has his talent. I've tried to do it on my own. Yeah again - it's not work. Here's my code:

```
$sql_rCost="select date,
       substring_index(cost, '-', 1) type_a,
       case when cost regexp '.*-' then
                 substring_index(substring_index(cost, '-', 2), '-', -1)
            else ''
       end type_b,
       case when cost regexp '.*-.*-' th                substring_index(substring_index(cost, '-', 3), '-', -1)
            else ''
       end type_c,
       case when cost regexp '.*-.*-.*-' then
            substring_index(substring_index(cost, '-', 4), '-', -1)
            else ''
       end type_d,
       case when cost regexp '.*-.*-.*-.*-' then
            substring_index(substring_index(cost, '-', 5), '-', -1)
            else ''
       end type_e
from room_rate_cost where rate='2' and  hotel='1' and date between '2012-11-01' and '2012-11-31' order by date asc
";
$result_rCost=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql_rCost);
while($rec_rCost=mysql_fetch_array($result_rCost)){
    $_rCostDBdate=$rec_rCost['date'];
    $_rCostDBtypea=$rec_rCost['type_a'];
    $_rCostDBtypeb=$rec_rCost['type_b'];
    $_rCostDBtypec=$rec_rCost['type_c'];
    $_rCostDBtyped=$rec_rCost['type_d'];
    $_rCostDBtypee=$rec_rCost['type_e'];

    $_rCostDBcost[]=$rec_rCost['cost'];

    $_array[]=array(    $_rCostDBdate,$_rCostDBcost);
}
    echo "{\"data\": [".json_encode($_array)."]}";
```

After execute it the returns is:

```
{"data": [[["2012-11-01",[null]],["2012-11-02",[null,null]],["2012-11-03",[null,null,null]],["2012-11-04",[null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-05",[null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-06",[null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-07",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-08",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-09",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-10",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-11",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-12",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-13",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-14",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-15",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-16",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-17",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-18",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-19",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-20",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-21",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-22",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-23",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-24",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-25",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-26",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-27",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-28",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-29",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]],["2012-11-30",[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]]]}
```

The expected format is :

```
    {
  "data": [
    ["", "type_a", "type_b", "type_c", "type_d", "type_e"],
    ["2011-11-01", 4700, 5500, 6100, 6600, 7300],
    ["2011-11-02", 4700, 5500, 6100, 6600, 7300],
    ["2011-11-03", 4700, 5500, 6100, 6600, 7300],
    ...
    ["2011-11-30", 4700, 5500, 6100, 6600, 7300],
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your code looks more like php rather than jquery to me, isn't it? I would retag it so the proper experts find your question.

Comment: @OlafDietsche next time, you may edit the tags yourself ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the array creation from:

```
$_array[]=array($_rCostDBdate,$_rCostDBcost);
```

to:

```
$_array[]=array($_rCostDBdate, $_rCostDBtypea, $_rCostDBtypeb, $_rCostDBtypec,
                $_rCostDBtyped, $_rCostDBtypee);
```

and would leave out the line:

```
$_rCostDBcost[]=$rec_rCost['cost'];
```

since in the query result, there is no column named `cost`.

If you change the query to `mysql_fetch_array($result_rCost,  MYSQL_NUM)`, you could reduce the loop to just:

```
while ($rec_rCost = mysql_fetch_array($result_rCost,  MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $_array[] = $rec_rCost;
}
```

**Update**:
To add the header line, just insert before the loop:

```
$_array[] = array('', 'type_a', 'type_b', 'type_c', 'type_d', 'type_e');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it very close. But one thing missing is the room type name : type_a, type_b... type_e. 

`["", "type_a", "type_b", "type_c", "type_d", "type_e"],`

I've tried your code. They're works well for the rate cost. Please suggest.

Comment: The code is nearly complete but on "[" before the first date is unexpected. `{"data": [["", "type_a", "type_b", "type_c", "type_d", "type_e"],[["2012-11-01","1100","","","",""],["2012-11-02","1100","","","",""],`

Comment: Before 2012-11-01 you'll see that there're two "[". It must have only one to meet the json format. Please suggest

Comment: If mysql resulted like this : `["Superior"],["Deluxe - City View"],["Deluxe - Balcony"],["Junior Suite"],["Andaman Studio"], `but I want it to be formated like this : `["Superior","Deluxe - City View","Deluxe - Balcony","Junior Suite","Andaman Studio"]`, how could I do that?

Comment: MySQL is : `$sql_rName="select title from room_db where hotel='1' order by id asc";
$result_rName=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql_rName);
while($rec_rName=mysql_fetch_array($result_rName)){
 $_rName=$rec_rName['title'];
 $_array[]=array($_rName);
}`

Comment: Just leave out the last `array()`: `$_array[]=$_rName;`. But please don't squeeze such unrelated questions into comments. It's better to ask a new question.

Comment: Okey I'll create a new topic. Please follow me then :)

Comment: A new topic has been created : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237525/mysql-reformat-mysql-result-to-meet-json-hansontable

Comment: @Wilf No need for this one. I think this one is solved, isn't it?

Comment: yeah. The issue seems to be solved but this is just a sample of code which I need to adapt to a real database. In fact, type_a, type_b... type_e is just a guide line for one hotel (hotel='1'). When hotel='2' the room names are also change. This is why I need to re-query a set of room name from room_db in $_array before loop.

Comment: No problem. You've helped me a lot. Hope you'll pushing me to the line.