# MySQL reformat mysql result to meet json hansontable

Tags: mysql, json, format

According to my previous solved issue : [Re-arrange mysql result in an expected format for hansontable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221142/re-arrange-mysql-result-in-an-expected-format-for-hansontable/13221932). I'm going to re-format mysql result from

> ["Superior"],["Deluxe - City View"],["Deluxe - Balcony"],["Junior
>   Suite"],["Andaman Studio"]

into

```
["Superior","Deluxe - City View","Deluxe - Balcony","Junior Suite","Andaman Studio"]
```

From these codes:

```
$sql_rName="select title from room_db where hotel='1' order by id asc";
$result_rName=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql_rName);
while($rec_rName=mysql_fetch_array($result_rName)){
    $_rName=$rec_rName['title'];
    $_array[]=$_rName;
}
echo "{\"data\": ".json_encode($_array)."}";
```

mysql Table : room_db
[image: room_db]

Please suggest.

ps. Thanks to Olaf Dietsche for all of these help.

Comment: So what is the problem you are having?

Comment: @MikeBrant. I'm having these result : `["Superior"],["Deluxe - City View"],["Deluxe - Balcony"],["Junior Suite"],["Andaman Studio"]` instead of `["Superior","Deluxe - City View","Deluxe - Balcony","Junior Suite","Andaman Studio"]`. I need the result to be formated in the second one.

Comment: what is var_dump of $_array show after it is built in the loop? It should just be a numerically indexed array.

Comment: @MikeBrant. Well, neither $_array[]=array($_rName); nor $_array[]=$_rName; works in this case.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Because `$_array[]=$_rName;` should produce the output you have shown above. What else is needed?

Answer (score 2):

To make a correct JSON, Try :
`

```
$result="select title from room_db where hotel='1' order by id asc";    
$messages = array();
            while($message_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $message = array(
                'id' => $message_data['userid'],
                'title' => $message_data['title']
                );
                $messages[] = $message;
                }
                echo json_encode($messages);
            }
`
```

and on the reseiver side do this :

```
`
data1=$.parseJSON(data);

            if(data1.length===0){

                $('#table > #table_body').append('<tr><td colspan="4" align="center" style="color:red">NO matching data </td></tr>');
                }
        else{
            for(var i=0;i<data1.length;i++)
            {
                $('#table > #table_body').append('<tr id="' + data1[i]['id'] +'"> <td id="' + data1[i]['id'] +'" align="center" <td>'+data1[i]['title']+'</td> </tr>');
            }
            }
            $('#table').append('</tbody>');

    `
```

Comment: thank you very much for your attempt. I'll try it and let you know.